# Store time while inserting data into oracle table

Tags: oracle, sysdate

In one of my column, I want to store time also in below condition. Here is the query below.

```
APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END,
```

how to add time part in `SYSDATE` here

Comment: Sysdate already has time component in it. Its just the representation which you can do using to_char

Comment: @XING: but its not showing the time part while binding.can u update the code for `to_char` and show

Comment: What do you mean to say `not showing the time part while binding` .. Where are you binding. You must post the complete scenario as in what and how you tried

Comment: @XING: in my front end part, it stores in table as `05-01-18`

Comment: So when you replace `SYSDATE` with `to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` , it doesnot work. Is that what you say ?

Comment: @VVVV, what is that "front end part"? For example, if it is an Oracle Forms application or Apex, you should modify item's **Format mask** property and set it to display time component too. For example, dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already there; if you don't see it, it is because your NLS settings. Here's an example of what you might do: ALTER SESSION or use TO_CHAR:

```
SQL> create table test (approved_Date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

APPROVED
--------
05.01.18

SQL> select to_char(approved_Date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from test;

TO_CHAR(APPROVED_DA
-------------------
05.01.2018 10:37:38

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

APPROVED_DATE
----------------------
05-01-2018 10:37:38 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: can u add in my `case` condition. i tried that but it was not working

Comment: You don't have to add anything to your CASE statement; it works OK. Your problem is in *DISPLAYING* that value, and I showed you how to do it properly. The most usual way is to apply TO_CHAR function with desired format mask.

Answer (score 0):

you CASE code is running perfectly fine. you just need to change your display setting as sysdate already have time element in it.

if you are using PL/SQL go to

tools > preference > Date/Time

and change to format as per your requirement.

and while accessing this field use `to_char(sysdate , 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')`